# How to connect mobile app ( ionic/angular ) to dynamic crm via azure ad

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, mobile, dynamic, crm

I was wondering how I could connect a mobile app created in ionic to azure, the app needs to interact with Dynamics CRM where all the data is. My guess is that I have to login via Azure AD , get the token, create API endpoints in Azure ( which service? ) or expose them, nd query the endpoint with the token.

Is this the right workflow?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much on the right track. You can host your API in an Azure App Service. You can also secure it by integrating Azure AD with your app service using your token. This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad) walks through using a front-end and back-end app and securing communication with it. Since your already have a front-end, you can ignore those steps. Although the same is a .NET Core application, the same applies if you were to write your API in NodeJS or another language.

Hope this helps.